# RedirectToUmbracoPage with custom model after form post?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

How can I do a POST and `RedirectToUmbracoPage()` with a custom model.  As far as I can tell, `RedirectToUmbracoPage` takes a nodeId, but I couldn't tell how to pass it my custom model.  The model I have does inherit from `RenderModel`, but I am getting the error that my view expects my custom model, but it was passed a RenderModel.

Initially, I was just returning `View("page")`, but this causes another post on refresh, so what I would really like to do is redirect the user?  Also, I am not sure if a `POST` is what I need because I am basically searching a database and returning results, I am actually not saving any data, but I am not sure how to do what I want with a `GET`?

In a nutshell, I want to search a database with some Form values, get the data into a model and redirect the user to another page with my model?

Below works without a custom model, now it is just a matter of getting that in there.

```
var nodeId = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPage.GetProperty("NoProductsFoundUrl").DataValue);

return RedirectToUmbracoPage(nodeId);
```

Comment: Great answer. They are constantly changing Umbraco. Version 9 is .NET Core and although the above answer works for v8.x.x, it may not work for later versions

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a `ChildAction` for this:

- On your template you do `@Html.Action("DoSearch", "Search")` - calling the action `DoSearch` on the `SearchController`
- In your controller you have a `DoSearch` method, decorated with `[ChildActionOnly]` (this attribute is not required but it stops people from using the method in any other way than `@Html.Action`
- The controller does the search and returns your custom view that can accept your custom model, for example: `return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/SearchPartial.cshtml", model);`
- You partial accepts your custom model `@model My.Custom.SearchModel`

Comment: A few questions:  Currently I have a `ProductsFilter` partial which has the search form because I use it in multiple places.  I am returning a view (not a partial) from an `ActionResult` in `ProductsFilterController`, is that fine too?  The issue is that I stay the url stays the same and if the user clicks refresh, it does a POST again.  Does `@Html.Action` take POST values from a form `(@Html.BeginUmbracoForm)`?

Comment: Also, it isn't a big deal, but it would be nice to have some be able to bookmark the page so they can send the `URL` to someone and get search results.  Right now it is a `POST`, do you know if it is possible to do a `GET` with `@Html.Action`?  and would it still need to be a `ChildAction`?

Comment: You decide if you want to do a `POST` or `GET`, the action can be something like `public ActionResult Search(string query)` and that will find the variable `query` in either one. If you make it a `GET` then it's obviously easy to bookmark for the future.

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask, was that does `SearchController` have to inherit from `SurfaceController`?

Comment: Not necessarily but it is really helpful do inherit from `SurfaceController` to get easy access to the Umbraco Services API and Umbraco helpers. `SurfaceController` just inherits from `Controller` adding easy access to Umbraco-specific methods.

Comment: Is it possible to invoke @Html.Action from a submit?  I don't want to fire once a page renders because the user has to select search options from dropdowns first and then I want to invoke the action?